# Fixing a non-working search field and table in Fusion Tables map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm stuck with an adjusted piece of code from Github. [The source][https://github.com/chrislkeller/failed-us-banks-since-2000] is this excellent map on U.S. Bank failures. [Live example here][http://www.projects.chrislkeller.com/failed-us-banks-since-2000/].

I want to make a map with all the players on Euro 2012. [Here's live example][http://www.jerryvermanen.nl/ekkaart/index.html] of how far I've come.

I have two main problems on this map (ignoring the info window, which still misses an extra field with the number of players in that particular competition.
- My search field doesn't work. Why? What adjustment in code can fix this?
- If I click my table, it doesn't snap to the competition (the KML of the country in which the competition is organised). Again, why doesn't it work and how can I make it work?

Check my code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- begin meta -->
<title>Selecties EK 2012</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Ek 2012, voetbal, selecties" />
<meta name="description" content=">Vind alle spelers die naar het EK voetbal 2012 gaan op land van herkomst en club." />
<!-- end meta -->

<!-- begin css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- end header -->

<!-- begin body -->
<body onload="initialize()">

<!-- begin map container -->
<div id="map-container">

<!-- begin action bar -->
<div id ="map-action-bar">

</div>
<!-- end action bar -->

<!-- begin map -->
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<!-- end map -->

<!--begin map explainer -->
<div id="map-explainer">
<h1>Selecties EK 2012</h1>
<p>Op ... juni begint het EK voetbal 2012. De 24 deelnemende landen strijden voor een plek in de finale op ... juli, om vervolgens tot Europees Kampioen gekroond te worden.</p>

<p>Op welke spelers staan de schijnwerpers tijdens deze voetbalmaand? En welke competities leveren de meeste EK-gangers af?</p>

<!-- begin credits -->
<div id="smalltype">
<p>Gemaakt door <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/JerryVermanen" target="_blank">Jerry Vermanen.</a>
<p>Code via <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/ChrisLKeller" target="_blank">Chris Keller.</a></br>
<a href="www.jerryvermanen.nl" target="_blank">Download de data</a><br />
<a href="https://github.com/chrislkeller/failed-us-banks-since-2000" target="_blank">Code op GitHub</a>
</p>
</div>
<!-- end credits -->

</div>
<!-- end map explainer -->

<!-- begin table -->
<div id="visualization"></div>
<!-- end table -->

</div>
<!-- end map container -->

</body>
<!-- end body -->

<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=us"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ek2012.js"></script>
<!-- end scripts -->

<!-- begin analytics code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setaccount', '']);
  _gaq.push(['_setdomainname', '']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackpageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createelement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getelementsbytagname('script')[0]; s.parentnode.insertbefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- end analytics code -->

</html>
<!-- end document -->
```

And the js-file

```
//write the map on page load
$(document).ready(function() {

    createMap();

});


//select menu - out-thought myself with this one and couldn't create dynamically
var searchVariables = '<select id="newComp">' +
'<option value="">Alle competities</option>' +
'<option value="Belgische competitie">Belgische competitie</option>' +
'<option value="Bundesliga">Bundesliga</option>' +
'<option value="Championship">Championship</option>' +

'</select>' +
'<select id="NewClub">' +
'<option value="">Alle EK-landen</option>' +
'<option value="ZWE">ZWE</option>' +
'<option value="IER">IER</option>' +
'</select>' +
'<input type="button" class="mapActionButton" value="Search" id="searchBanks" onclick="changeSearch()"/>' +
'<input type="button" class="mapActionButton" value="Reset Map" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href" />';

//ft layer
var layer; 

//ft table
var tableid = 3976074;

//map
var map;

//geocoder instance
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

//gviz
var table;

//FT data in gviz object
var datatable;

//infowindow
var infowindow;

//center of map
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(40,0);

//default zoom
var zoom = 1;

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});

function createMap() {

        //map options
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            center: center,
            zoom: zoom,
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 6,
            scrollwheel: true,      
            disableDragging: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP}
        });

        //intial fusion layer & supress fusion info window
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid, {suppressInfoWindows: true});
        layer.setQuery("SELECT Location FROM " + tableid);
        layer.setMap(map);

        //writes the select menus to the search bar     
        document.getElementById('map-action-bar').innerHTML = searchVariables;

        //adds click listener on layer
        google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
        if(infowindow) infowindow.close();
        else infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            //write FT data to info window
            text = infowindow.setContent(
                '<p>De ' + e.row['Competitie'].value +
                ' levert ' + e.row['Speler'].value +
                ' internationals.'
            );          

            infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
            map.setCenter(e.latLng);
            infowindow.open(map);       
        });

        //query FT data for visualization
        var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT Speler, Competitie, Land, Club FROM 3976074 ORDER BY Speler ASC");
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
        query.send(getData);
}


        //write FT data to table
        function getData(response) {
            table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            datatable = response.getDataTable();
            table.draw(datatable, {showRowNumber: true});

            //add table listener when row clicked
            google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);
        }
        //end function


        //match table data to map data
        function selectHandler() {

            //get lat/lng from FT
                var selection = table.getSelection();
                var Competitie = datatable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
                var Club = datatable.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);
                var Speler = datatable.getValue(selection[0].row, 2);
                var Land = datatable.getValue(selection[0].row, 3);

            infoWindowContent = (
            '<p>De ' + e.row['Competitie'].value +
                ' levert ' + e.row['Speler'].value +
                ' internationals.'
            );  

        }


        /* search function based on user's selection
        that I wrote longhand, though there must 
        be some kind of shortcut because I'm basically
        rewriting the main function again? */
        function changeSearch(comper, cluber) {
            if(infowindow) infowindow.close();
            layer.setMap();

                //assigns select menu values to variables
                comper = document.getElementById('newComp').value;
                cluber = document.getElementById('newClub').value;

            //sets new layer to map
            layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid, {suppressInfoWindows: true});

            //with a query based on the variables
            layer.setQuery("SELECT Location FROM " + tableid + " WHERE Competitie CONTAINS '" + comper + "' AND Land CONTAINS '" + cluber);

            //and sets the map
            layer.setMap(map);

            /* here we build the table again but based on the variables from the menu values */
            var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT Speler, Competitie, Land, Club" + tableid + " WHERE Competitie CONTAINS '" + comper + "' AND Land CONTAINS '" + cluber + "' ORDER BY 'Speler' ASC");
            var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
            query.send(getData);

            //adds a click listener on search layer
            google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
             if(infowindow) infowindow.close();
             else infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                //writes the info window on search layer
                infowindow.setContent(
                '<p>De ' + e.row['Competitie'].value +
                ' levert ' + e.row['Speler'].value +
                ' internationals.'
            );  

                infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
                map.setCenter(e.latLng);
                infowindow.open(map);
            });

        }
        //end function

  [1]: https://github.com/chrislkeller/failed-us-banks-since-2000
  [2]: http://www.projects.chrislkeller.com/failed-us-banks-since-2000/
  [3]: http://www.jerryvermanen.nl/ekkaart/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplyfied your example a little bit and put it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/SdX4h/

You basically had 2 minor errors:

- The id of the 2nd select box was "NewClub" but you access it with "newClub", this does not work as `document.getElementById()` is case-sensitive
- The SQL query that you generate in the `changeSearch()` function was wrong

This:

```
var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT Speler, Competitie, Land, Club" + tableid + " WHERE Competitie CONTAINS '" + comper + "' AND Land CONTAINS '" + cluber + "' ORDER BY 'Speler' ASC");
```

should be:

```
var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT Speler, Competitie, Land, Club FROM " + tableid + " WHERE Competitie CONTAINS '" + comper + "' AND Land CONTAINS '" + cluber + "' ORDER BY 'Speler' ASC");
```

It is not necessary do recreate the FusionTablesLayer every time you change the values of the search, you can use the following syntax (which also prevents you from the SQL error above):

```
var fields = "Speler, Competitie, Land, Club";
var tableId = 3976074;
var whereClause = "Competitie CONTAINS '" + comper + "' AND Land CONTAINS '" + cluber + "'";
layer.setOptions({
   query: {
            select: fields,
            from: tableId,
            where: whereClause
   }
});
```

Comment: It works partially. Thanks for fixing the search, but now I encounter the following problems:

1.) The KML's disappear after a search. For example, the KML-file of Belgium should show as only country after a search on Belgische Competitie.

2.) The KML's don't display an info window anymore.

3.) The table is still not 'clickable'.

Comment: 1) I fixed it, I didn't get the functionality first. It's important, that you need to query the Location column for the FusionTablesLayer 2) & 3) I removed the info window for simplicity. But now I re-added it. Does it work as expected now? See jsFiddle for all changes.